# Make HorizontalSplitPanel adjust its width to content- in Vaadin 7

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

I am using `Vaadin 7` rc1.

I would like to create a `HorizontalSplitPanel` that adjusts its width if the left side is wider then the given width. 
The default behaviour is that a scrollbar appears on at the bottom of the screen if the content is wider then the given size. However I would like to have the left side widened.

I am new to Vaadin and the book does not go into details like this.
How is this possible in `Vaadin 7`?
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The answer might be easier and more exact if you share your code in the question text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call method [setSizeFull()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#setSizeFull%28%29) on the HorizontalSplitPanel.

Then open the application in e.g. Chrome and Inspect the split panel element. See what has been changed and try to play with width/height values in the inspector. That might give you a clue what is wrong. Maybe you need to call setSizeFull() also on components that are contained in split panel?

Answer (score 0):

The is a function in HorizontalSplitPanel that do exactly what you looking for :

```
panel.setSplitPosition(float f, Unit unit);
```

You can use either

> Unit.PERCENTAGE

or

> Unit.PX

... there is a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score -2):

I have managed to solve the situation with other layout structure.